# cURL is not working? No errors but doesnt work

Tags: php, curl

im having problem with cURL...

My code:

```
            $ffmpegExecUrl = preg_replace('/(([^\/]+?)(\.php))$/', "exec_ffmpeg.php", "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $postData = "cmd=".urlencode($exec_string)."&token=".urlencode($this->_uniqueID);
            $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ffmpegExecUrl);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
```

I got cURL enabled in my host and its not giving any error on error_log, but it just doesnt go to that exec_ffmpeg.php...

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you using preg_replace() for file name??

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work" how do you know it isn't going to the target URL? Consider checking `curl_getinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);" you have to catch the transfer:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and put a "hardcoded" URL to see if that works for you? 
This would check if your regular expression works or not.

At least you can `print "$ffmpegExecUrl"` to a logfile.

Try to make the timeout longer than 1 or just comment out the entry for the test.

Please give us the results you get so we can try and help you further.

Comment: What you mean by hardcoded url?

I set timeout to longer, but sill not working.
I have set my script to print FFMPEG command, which exec_ffmpeg.php should run. I tested that command its giving to me on new test file and its working there.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need the cURL extension enabled in the PHP.ini if you haven't already. Actually thinking about it - it would likely have complained about cURL being unknown